# What is the difference between ICR and OCR?

Tags: reference-request, ocr

I've just found the term "Intelligent Character Recognition" (ICR) on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_character_recognition) and [other](https://abbyy.technology/en:features:scenario:zonal_field-level-ocr) [pages](https://www.chronoscan.org/doc/ocr_icr___optical_intelligent_character_recognition.htm). According to Wikipedia:

> In computer science, intelligent character recognition (ICR) is an advanced optical character recognition (OCR) or — rather more specific — handwriting recognition system that allows fonts and different styles of handwriting to be learned by a computer during processing to improve accuracy and recognition levels.

Is this just a marketing stunt or are there actually techniques which are specified as OCR and other techniques which are ICR? Are there Conferences / Journals about OCR which distinguish between OCR and ICR? (If yes, please add a reference)